# OAuth design for API without users permission

Tags: api, oauth

I am developing an API that will be used by users of my customers.  Here is what the flow will look like:

1. User of my cloud based service creates an API key.
2. User embeds the API key into their own custom applications.
3. User deploys the application to their own end users.
4. The application talks to our API.

I am looking for advice on how to secure this API.  I see a few issues:

1. API key has to be embedded into the users application and is therefore vulnerable to being stolen and abused.
2. Once an API key is compromised, it can easily be disabled, but how will my users update their applications to use a new API key short of having to rebuild the application and redeploy.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to design this?

Comment: Your issue 1: API key has to be embedded... Why is that? What language/platform are you using?

Comment: The API can't be wide open.  I am collecting information from the application on behalf of the users of my system.  So I need to make sure that the information is legit and that it goes to the right account in our system.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Eric, how did you end up implementing this well? Every method I can think of to secure an API *requires* some form of public/private key that all suffer from this safe vulnerability. I am specifically thinking of those Android apps that were downloaded/reposted earlier this year with malware in them. FWIW, Twitter seems to solve this problem by issuing public/private keys per *application*, not per account, so if an app is compromised, the whole app is turned off until a new version with new keys is rolled out. http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Comment: Each customer gets a public api key for their product, they do their best to keep this api key safe, but it's impossible to keep it completely safe.  So when an app requests permission to submit cases to our api they present that api key and they receive an oauth token in exchange.  We keep track of any IPs that might be abusing us and we use SSL for all communication.  Users can also disable and create new API keys.  This seems to be about the best we can do.

Comment: Eric, thank you for clarifying. Sounds like a perfectly reasonable (and safe) approach.

Comment: Eric - thanks, we've reached the same conclusion that you have. One question though - why do you need to involve OAuth? Isn't it sufficient to simply pass the API key on every transaction and verify it?  Also, assuming you've deployed this, how has it worked out for you?  Any suggestions for improvements, ways to detect bogus transactions, frequency of API key rollover, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: We are using OAuth so that we are working with auth tokens instead of the API key.  When a client tries to connect to our service for the 1st time, they are given an oauth token that is specific to them and, from then on, that is what they pass with each API call. Everything seems to be working well.  We haven't had any issues.

Comment: @EricJ.Smith : I have may be a silly question. I have decided to implement public API key/Shared Secret Key combo per user of my android app which will access my API. I will send the keys to each user when he registers for our api through email. Now what I dont understand how user will let know my android app about these keys? One option is to allow them to be used when user logs in to app. But it would be irritating to enter long(at least 30-40 chars) keys instead of simple username and password everytime they Log-in to app.

Comment: @EricJ.Smith : in continuation with my previous comment another option I think is to exchange the shared secret as response to login request and use it for every subsequent request until user logs out..is this good aproach as i read that shared secrets are not to be sent on wire ever?

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken but maybe you could have your customers' users talk to your customers' APIs instead. Basically, your customers would keep their secret key on their servers, and not embed them in the clients they give their users, so it couldn't be hijecked (unless their server was compromised of course). Then the users would talk to your API through your customers' APIs.

It would be slower and need more work on the part of your customers, but also safer.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that I can see to this, although I'm sure there are more..

1. Use oauth's RSA signature method, and implement a secure certification exchange of keys using your "cloud based service" as the exchange mechanism (or a public cert provider).
2. Implement a service that allows clients to "renew" their consumer key/secret automatically, but then secure that mechanism using RSA or some other public key encryption method.

Both of these are not easy, and would require your user's applications to "phone home" in order to update their consumer keys.

In the future I think OAuth 2 will provide at least protocol definitions for things like this, but for now, if you're using OAuth 1.0a, what you want to do doesn't really fit into the spec very well (i.e. you have to design much of it yourself.)

Comment: Since the application is being distributed to a bunch of untrusted users, wouldn't any one of them simply be able to decompile the app and get the consumer and secret keys and be able to abuse the service?

I can't figure out a way that will prevent that type of abuse.  The only thing I can think of is to have the ability to block IPs that are abusing the service.